# Counting recursion without counters?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a complex system with recursive calls, this system calls my function.

Is there a "hacky" solution to see how far the current function is in the recursive calling tree without using counters?

(can't use counters because i can't change unknown compiled code from way back)

[edit]
one way i came up with is printing/looking at the stacktrace, but hoping for a cleaner way.

Comment: Can't you use a stactic variable so your function increments it everytime it is called?

Comment: The stacktrace is probably the cleanest and most clear info you will get. Unless you can't change the code, that will be your best and quickest option.

Comment: I understand that you can't change other code in the system; but you are talking about YOUR function. So why can't you put a counter into that function of yours?

Comment: @marcellorvalle  Jägermeister when i use a static variable and increment it every time my function is called i get the calling total (how many times my function was called). I need to to know how deep my function is in the calling tree. Or am i totally confused and are they the same? (recursion always confuses me a bt)

Comment: @TinusTate -If your function is called on every recursion step you could consider each increment as a deeper call. I just can't figure out how to reset the counter after the last recursive call.

Comment: @marcellorvalle Cheers! Indeed that would work if the function would be called in every step, but it's never easy ;-) Maybe there is no other solution then writing a code that parses the stacktrace and counts the calls.